# I am given a warning to include android:targetSdkVersion in my AndroidManifest, but it is already included?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, tags, warnings

I have the following in my AndroidManifest.xml;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="cmb.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="15" android:minSdkVersion="8" />

</manifest>
```

However, Eclipse gives me the warning;

```
<uses-sdk> should specify a target API level (the highest verified
version; when running on later versions, compatibility behaviors may
be enabled) with android:targetSdkVersion="?"
```

My project build target is Google APIs 4.0.3 (15), and I originally had the targetSdkVersion as 8, but changing it to 15 has not removed the warning.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Do check Project->Properties->Android to see if the targetSdkVersion is set to 15. I've had problems when these two values disagree.

Comment: It's definitely set to Google APIs (15) in this property window.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically, the problem was that changes to xml files were not being noticed by the validator in Eclipse (although I can't confirm that the issue is actually with Eclipse). This happened for a number of files and re-building did not help. I ended up reloading the project or deleting and re-writing the files to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Also check with the project.properties, project target will also be reflected there once you updated it in the manifest.xml if not you can modify it at your own.

Comment: The line in project.properties reads; target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:15, which is what I specified. I am wondering if the fact that it's Google APIs rather than Android, which is obviously necessary, causes this and that it's just a small bug.